# Cauchy problem and right-saturated solution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the Cauchy problem
\begin{equation}
    x''+ax+f(x')=0, x(t_0)=x_0, x'(t_0)=x_1, (1)
\end{equation}
where $a$ is a positive constant, and $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a locally Lipschitz function satisfying
$$
yf(y) \geq 0, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}
$$
Prove that any right-saturated solution of $(1)$ is defined on the semi-axis $[t_0, \infty)$.

Could you helpe me? I'm trying to solve using
$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|x'(t)|^2+a|x'(t)|^2 \leq0, \forall t \geq t_0$ and conclude that $x$ and $x'$ are bounded...

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying $x'$ yields
$$x''x'+axx'\leq x''x'+axx'+f(x')x'=0.$$
Hence we know $\frac{1}{2}|x'(t)|^2+\frac{a}{2}|x(t)|^2$ is non-increasing. By $x(t_0)=x_0$ and $x'(t_0)=x_1$, we have $$\frac{1}{2}|x'(t)|^2+\frac{a}{2}|x(t)|^2\leq\frac{1}{2}{x_1}^2+\frac{a}{2}{x_0}^2,$$ which implies $x(t)$ and $x'(t)$ are bounded in their domains.